# htaccess - redirect not working as expected?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I need to setup a couple of redirects on my website. My htaccess file is currently:

```
RewriteEngine on
RedirectMatch 301 ^/browse/ http://www.mysite.co.uk/designs
Redirect /designs http://www.mysite.co.uk/our-designs
```

**Redirect #1** - I need to redirect all old urls that used to be `www.mysite.co.uk/browse/....` to `www.mysite.co.uk/designs/....` (designs folder replaces browse folder)

an example being:

```
http://www.mysite.co.uk/browse/home/kitchens
```

needs to go too:

```
http://www.mysite.co.uk/designs/home/kitchens
```

**Redirect #2** - now the second redirect is causing problems. I need to redirect just the page:

```
http://www.mysite.co.uk/designs
```

to:

```
http://www.mysite.co.uk/our-designs
```

So i use:

```
Redirect /designs http://www.mysite.co.uk/our-designs
```

This redirects the `/designs` page to `our-designs` page correctly but now also changes any url with `/designs/` in so from the example above

```
http://www.mysite.co.uk/designs/home/kitchens
```

should stay as it is but it changes to:

```
http://www.mysite.co.uk/our-designs/home/kitchens
```

which gives me a page not found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following rules:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^browse/(.+)$ /designs/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^designs/?$ /our-designs [R=301,L]
```

You can put the `http://www.mysite.co.uk` as a host to rewritten URLs if the hosts are different.

Answer (score 0):

Change order of your rules and add a query parameter to prevent further redirection:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^_noredir(&|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^designs/(.*)$ /our-designs/$1 [R=301,L,NC,NE]

RewriteRule ^browse/(.*)$ /designs/$1?_noredir [R=301,L,NE,NC,QSA]
```